# Programmatically list all directory resources on the Java classpath

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'm trying to get all the directory resources on the classpath in a Java application with a given prefix, and the code below works if the resources are in the filesystem but not if they are in a JAR file.

Here's the code I am using:

```
public class ClasspathHelperTest
{
   @Test
   public void test() throws Exception
   {
      ClassLoader effectiveClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      String pkg = "mydirectory/";
      Enumeration<URL> resources = effectiveClassLoader.getResources(pkg);

      Assert.assertTrue(resources.hasMoreElements());
      while (resources.hasMoreElements())
      {
         System.out.println(resources.nextElement());
      }
   }
}
```

Suppose I have the following test data:

Local filesystem:

/some/directory/path/mydirectory/file.data

Then I run the code above like this:

```
java -cp .:/junit.jar:/some/directory/path org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ClasspathHelperTest
```

It correctly finds and prints the resource:

```
file:/some/directory/path/mydirectory/
```

But if I create a jar file (/some/directory/path/test.jar) that contains mydirectory/file.data, and run the test with the Jar file on the classpath, it doesn't find the resource:

```
java -cp .:/junit.jar:/some/directory/path/test.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ClasspathHelperTest
```

Yields:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:27)
at ClasspathHelperTest.test(ClasspathHelperTest.java:20)
```

What is the correct way to make this work for directory resources inside a Jar file?

Comment: There is no correct way as JAR files are basically ZIP files which do not have directories. Some tools create empty files within the ZIP/JAR file as pseudo directory entries but you should not rely on that. There’s no feature like listing the contents of such a directory entry anyway.

Comment: In this case, the directory contains files, so the directory will have to be represented inside the Jar file

Comment: No, directories are usually *not* represented. A ZIP/JAR file consists of a flat list of entries having *qualified names*. So the presence of an entry `foo/bar` indicates the virtual presence of a directory `foo/` but `getResource` will not return such a directory without an explicit entry.